# Symfony2 - Issue with writing tests for a controller that is being passed an object as a param

Tags: symfony, phpunit, twig

I'm running into an issue with writing a test for a controller inside a Symonfy2 bundle.

The controller is only ever accessed via Twig's `{% render %}`, and works great in the application, but the test keep failing, no matter what way I approach it. Here is basically what's going on:

Controller `A`. - The "parent" controller. Loads via a typical URL.

Controller `B`.  Loaded via `{% render %}` from a template rendered by Controller `A`.  An object variable is passed to Controller `B` in the `{% render %}` tag.

Controller `C`.  Loaded via `{% render %}` from a template rendered by Controller `B`.

This all works great in the actual application, and having things structured this way allows for the maximum amount of code reuse.  The issue comes in when I started writing a unit test for Controller `B`.  Because this is an internal only controller, I thought it would be best call the methods for testing like this:

```php
$this->obj = new ControllerB();
$this->obj->setContainer($this->getContainer());
$this->obj->methodToTest();
```

But this leads me to this error message:

> Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request").") at line XX - *This is the line where we are attempting to render a method from Controller C via {% render %}*

So it seems that because the call to the method in Controller `B` was not part of a request, it can't make an internal sub-request to controller `C`.  The solution to that would seem make a request to controller `B` instead via:

```php
$this->client = static::createClient(...);
$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/routeToControllerB');
```

But this won't work either because I need to pass objects and arrays to the method in Controller `B`, and they are too big to `serialize/json_encode` and fit in the URL to request.

I've experimented to try and force a request into the objects container:

```php
    $this->client = static::createClient();
    $this->client->followRedirects();
    $container = $this->getContainer();
    $container->get('session')->start();
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $container->set('request', $request);

    $user = new \User(1111);
    \Auth::set_user($user);
    $user = new \Company\Component\Security\User\User(\Auth::user());
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, 'phpunit', 'PHPSESSID', $user->getRoles());
    $container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);

    $this->obj = new ControllerB();
    $this->obj->setContainer($container);
```

But so far I can't find anything that will let me test a controller method that needs to be passed an object and also uses `{% render %}` (an internal sub-request) in the template.  Anyone ever run into this before?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little but here my advices:

If you really want to do that, you can make your controller a service, give it all the dependencies it needs, and then write a unit test. See http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/06/symfony2-testing-your-controllers/

But I recommand you not to unit test your controllers. If they are well written, they don't contain any business logic and unit testing them is kind of pointless.
You should go with the functional test of your controller directly if there is an associated route (but in this case you won't be able to give it objects directly), otherwise if the controller is not designed to be accessed directly from a browser (because you give it objects, or just because you don't want to), just test the controller including it and it will cover both controllers. In your example, just test the controller A, and it covers B and C implicitly.